# How do you instantiate a DriveId/DriveFolder using the Google Drive Android API

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I am sure this is an easy question to answer, but I've been unable to find out how to instancate a `DriveId` and/or `DriveFolder` with the Drive resource id using the Google Drive Android API v 12.

I have read [the Google Drive Android API documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/create-file) and have managed to create a file on my Google Drive from my Android app in the root folder, but now I want to create the file in a specific folder and I'm unsure how to go about this.

A lot of the code I've seen (such as [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22515913/1912127)) uses the deprecated Google `DriveApi` to get a `DriveId` from the resource id of the folder.

I have tried to use the `DriveId` method `decodeFromString` but when I ran the following code, I get an error saying the DriveId is invalid:

```
String googleDriveFolderId = "16TwNeDF9_inOK4X5AaGnVMNycNVxxMtd";
DriveFolder projectFolder = DriveId.decodeFromString(googleDriveFolderId).asDriveFolder();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[Create a folder](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/folders#create_a_folder)

> To create a folder, call [DriveResourceClient.createFolder()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveResourceClient.html#createFolder(com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveFolder,com.google.android.gms.drive.MetadataChangeSet)), passing
>   in a reference to the parent folder and the metadata object containing
>   the title and other attributes to set the values for the folder.
>
> The following code sample demonstrates how to create a new folder in
>   the root folder:

```
private void createFolder() {
    getDriveResourceClient()
            .getRootFolder()
            .continueWithTask(task -> {
                DriveFolder parentFolder = task.getResult();
                MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                                                      .setTitle("New folder")
                                                      .setMimeType(DriveFolder.MIME_TYPE)
                                                      .setStarred(true)
                                                      .build();
                return getDriveResourceClient().createFolder(parentFolder, changeSet);
            })
            .addOnSuccessListener(this,
                    driveFolder -> {
                        showMessage(getString(R.string.file_created,
                                driveFolder.getDriveId().encodeToString()));
                        finish();
                    })
            .addOnFailureListener(this, e -> {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create file", e);
                showMessage(getString(R.string.file_create_error));
                finish();
            });
}
```

on Success, try calling [getDriveId()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveResource).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, unfortunately this does not answer my question which is: how do I create a DriveFolder and DriveId?

Comment: Thanks for the update to your answer. Unfortunately it still doesn't help me because I'm not creating a folder, I have a folder that already exists. See the code in my question.

Comment: are you trying to create a folder inside a folder? BTW you don't create DriveIDs, the server does that for you with each successful API request.

Comment: I have been given a folder that was created by someone else and shared with me and I am creating a file inside that folder

Comment: Isn't that the [Create file inside a folder](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/folders#create_file_inside_a_folder) that I posted earlier?

Comment: Yes but that method takes a DriveFolder. How do I instantiate DriveFolder? I have the id of the folder from the URL that I used to view the folder in my browser. I believe this is called the resource id.

Comment: This should provide the codes your looking for https://github.com/gsuitedevs/android-samples/tree/master/drive/demos

Comment: I have looked at those demos and haven't found the code I'm looking for.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/android/create-file#programmatically

Comment: Sorry I'm not being obtuse, but I have spent a couple hours already looking into this problem and can't find a solution. Maybe I'm not communicating my problem effectively because all the solutions you have proposed are not showing me how to instantiate a DriveFolder and DriveId. That code allows the user to pick a folder, which is not what I need. Thanks for the time.

Answer (score 0):

What I am trying to do is simply not possible using the Google Drive Android API. I guess this is because the `DriveResource` does not get a `resourceId` until it has been uploaded.

See this [SO answer which discusses how you aren't able to access any file or folder that isn't created by your app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27829239/1912127). I tested this and it's true - when I run a `Query` for a folder that I created manually in my root folder I cannot find it, but when I create a folder with the same name from my app, I get 1 query result.

Also see this [SO thread which says you need to use another Google Drive API (they suggested the REST API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50513817/uploading-a-file-to-google-drive/) to be able to specify a folder programmatically (without using a popup where the user selects a folder). Unfortunately that won't work for me because I am building an offline app - precisely the reason I chose to work with Google Drive.

I ended up making a compromise and working with the root folder - luckily for me my project is to be used with very specific Google accounts so I am able to do this. My code looks something like [this](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/android-samples/blob/021e756d763614d1f57c953083f8392f7189b686/drive/demos/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/CreateFileActivity.java#L46-L75):

```
private void createFile() {
    // [START create_file]
    final Task<DriveFolder> rootFolderTask = getDriveResourceClient().getRootFolder();
    final Task<DriveContents> createContentsTask = getDriveResourceClient().createContents();
    Tasks.whenAll(rootFolderTask, createContentsTask)
            .continueWithTask(task -> {
                DriveFolder parent = rootFolderTask.getResult();
                DriveContents contents = createContentsTask.getResult();
                OutputStream outputStream = contents.getOutputStream();
                try (Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream)) {
                    writer.write("Hello World!");
                }

                MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                                                      .setTitle("HelloWorld.txt")
                                                      .setMimeType("text/plain")
                                                      .setStarred(true)
                                                      .build();

                return getDriveResourceClient().createFile(parent, changeSet, contents);
            })
            .addOnSuccessListener(this,
                    driveFile -> {
                        showMessage(getString(R.string.file_created,
                                driveFile.getDriveId().encodeToString()));
                        finish();
                    })
            .addOnFailureListener(this, e -> {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create file", e);
                showMessage(getString(R.string.file_create_error));
                finish();
            });
    // [END create_file]
}
```

If you can't compromise and use the root folder, I would suggest that you create a folder from within your app into the root folder and then save the string representation of the DriveId which you can use the next time you run the code. I haven't yet tested if the folder could be used by another instance of the app running on a different device, but I would hope so (fingers crossed).

Another option is displaying a popup so the user can select the folder manually. See [this demo example](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/android-samples/blob/master/drive/demos/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/CreateFileInFolderActivity.java).

Comment: Another relevant Stack overflow thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33327219/drive-api-for-android-unable-to-access-the-file-created-by-same-app