# Android Drive API getWebViewLink return null

Tags: android, api, google-drive-api

I'm trying to create file on drive programmatically using Android app and Drive API then making a public link. I managed to make the file but the getWebViewLink,getAlternateLink,getEmbedLink always return null. I can't figure it out i and did not find any useful documentation on this.

my code:

```
private GoogleSignInClient buildGoogleSignInClient() {
        GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions =
                new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                        .requestScopes(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
                        .requestServerAuthCode(AUTH_CODE)
                        .build();
        return GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, signInOptions);
    }

private void createFile() {
final Task<DriveFolder> rootFolderTask = mDriveResourceClient.getRootFolder();
        final Task<DriveContents> createContentsTask = mDriveResourceClient.createContents();
        Tasks.whenAll(rootFolderTask, createContentsTask)
                .continueWithTask(task -> {
                    DriveFolder parent = rootFolderTask.getResult();
                    DriveContents contents = createContentsTask.getResult();
                    OutputStream outputStream = contents.getOutputStream();
                    try (Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream)) {
                        writer.write("Hello World 1!");
                    }
                    MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                            .setTitle("HelloWorld 1.txt")
                            .setMimeType("text/plain")
                            .setStarred(true)
                            .build();
                    return mDriveResourceClient.createFile(parent, changeSet, contents);

                })
                .addOnSuccessListener(this,
                        driveFile -> {
                            Log.d(TAG, "file created");
                            getMetaData(driveFile);

                        })
                .addOnFailureListener(this, e -> {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create file", e);

                });
    }

    private void getMetaData(DriveFile driveFile) {
        Task<Metadata> metadataTask = mDriveResourceClient.getMetadata(driveFile);
        metadataTask
                .addOnSuccessListener(this,
                        metadata -> {
                            Log.e(TAG, "metadata.getWebViewLink() " + metadata.getWebViewLink());
                        })
                .addOnFailureListener(this, e -> {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Unable to retrieve metadata", e);

                });
    }
```

Comment: I ended up using Google Drive REST API : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50513817/uploading-a-file-to-google-drive

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [link](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/issues/1257). It suggested to add the `webViewLink` in `files` property.

> ```
> $files = $drive->files->listFiles(array(
>       'q' => "'root' in parents",
>       'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name, webViewLink, mimeType)'
> ))->getFiles();
> ```